# Implementing LED in PyQt Designer

Tags: python, pyqt, qt-designer

I am new to PyQt and QtDesigner. I want to add an LED in my GUI. can anyone kindly suggest How can I add LED in my GUI and change its color in my application?

Comment: Hi Avanish, welcome to SO. An appropriate tutorial might be of help.

Comment: Hi @Chomel, I have seen some tutorials from [link] (http://zetcode.com/gui/pyqt4) and found some py qt apps from [link] (https://www.linux-apps.com/p/1132197/). However could not add this app on Qt Designer.

Answer (score 6):

I have implemented a green/red LED indicator in my application "Grid Control", please have a look at the code on [Github](https://github.com/akej74/grid-control) it may give you some ideas.

I have defined two LED icons in my resource file as follows:

```
ICON_RED_LED = ":/icons/led-red-on.png"
ICON_GREEN_LED = ":/icons/green-led-on.png"
```

The icon can activated like this:

```
self.ui.labelStatusFan1.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(ICON_RED_LED))
```

Also, by using signals, the icon can be activated based on some condition:

```
self.pixmap_signal_fan1.emit(ICON_RED_LED if fans_rpm[0] == 0 or fans_voltage[0] == 0 else ICON_GREEN_LED)
```

Comment: I took a look at your Grid Control application, it is very inspiring, thanks!